# Is it possible to configure one-time ssh or console login passwords using only packages from the official Arch Linux repositories?

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, security, login, password

I want to set up one-time passwords for both remote access via ssh and for local console login access to an Arch Linux server (no GUI anything).  The server runs in a small business environment and its function is primarily hosting KVM and LXC virtual machines.  The system is fully updated and running Linux kernel 4.9.6.

There have been packages in the past (i.e. OPIE) that were found to be buggy and insecure and were thus removed from most every distribution's official repositories.

There is currently a package called [OTPW](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/otpw.html) (One Time PassWord).  I've seen OTPW mentioned in several posts here, but with no description or commentary.  Regarding Arch Linux, OTPW is only available from the AUR.

So, my question is mainly just whether anyone knows of a solution available using only packages from the official Arch repositories.

Secondarily, does anyone know a reason why OTPW isn't in the official repositories?  Although I strongly prefer using official Arch packages, could OTPW or another another third party package provide a simple, secure solution?

Answer (score 0):

OTPW would be the easiest solution, it is in the main repo on ubuntu/debian fx. but not on RHEL where you have to compile it from source.

It is very secure, you can choose the entropy level depending on your paranoia.

It's also much easier to setup than OPIE or lambert fx.

Merkle is a spinoff from lambert that is more secure by doing a tree of hashes but is generally compute heavy, and very complex compared to OTPW.

If you don't trust third party package providers I suggest compiling from source: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/git/otpw